# how to store this data, by using hash, in redis

Tags: database, nosql, redis

I want to store an structure similiar to this.
The idea is make possible extract all the descriptions with the same id, I didnt see many examples in reddis, the documentation is very basic I think. Someone can tell me?

```
user:id:12:description:"nice"
user:id:12:description:"bad"
user:id:15:description:"nothing_especial"
...
```

I know that this is possible with hset, I tried with something like:

```
hset user id 12
hset user description "nice"
...
```

but the problem is that, when I try to insert the same key different times, HSET override the content value, and finally I have the same but with a different value

In the documentation I saw an example but was with Set, was something like this (i dont understand why they user a simple set....):

```
$ redis-cli set news:1:title "Redis is simple"
OK
$ redis-cli set news:1:url "http://code.google.com/p/redis"
OK
$ redis-cli lpush submitted.news 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this, At first I thought about this, but its limited because I cannot have more thatn one description for every user:

```
hset user id:1:deal "yeaaaaaaaah"
hset user id:1:description "sometifjjapodsifj"


hget user id:1:deal
    >yeaaaaaaaah
hget user id:1:description
    >sometifjjapodsifj
```

Finally the solution was this:

```
hset user1 description1 "asdoifjasdpofjaspdo"
hset user1 description2 "aosdifj"
hset user2 description1 "asdoijfaodsifj"
hset user2 description2 "asdoifjaposdifjaposdifjasdf"

hgetall user2
    >description1=asdoijfaodsifj
    >description2=asdoifjaposdifjaposdifjasdf
```